# como retornar una salida procedimientos almacenados MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Hace un tiempo vengo buscado por la web sobre como puedo retornar un OUT en MYSQL con procedimientos almacenados en php.

PHP

```
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $database_conexion);
$query_DatosWeb = sprintf("CALL genera_sesion()");
$DatosWeb = mysqli_query($conexion, $query_DatosWeb) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
$row_DatosWeb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosWeb);
$totalRows_DatosWeb = mysqli_num_rows($DatosWeb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que no existe un método nativo de mysqli para capturar los parámetros de salida de un procedimiento almacenado, como alternativa tendrías que crear una variable dinámica e incorporarla en la primera llamada del método, para posteriormente recuperar el resultado con un select, abajo te dejo un pequeño ejemplo.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("CALL genera_sesion(@param)");
$stmt->execute();
$select = $mysqli->query('SELECT @param');
$result = $select->fetch_assoc();
$param = $result['@param'];
var_dump($param);
```

No estoy muy seguro de como adecuarlo a tu caso, ya que me parece que tienes algunos métodos personalizados, es por esto que he puesto un ejemplo genérico. En este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014531/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedure-with-both-input-and-output-parameters-not) hablan un poco más a fondo de este tema por cierto, aunque está en ingles.

Comment: dale aver ahi lo checkeo que tal